# Probability of good colorings in randomly-colored graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Each vertex in a graph is randomly and independently colored either red or blue with equal probability. 
A coloring is called **$r$-good**, for some fraction $r\in[0,1]$, if at least a fraction $r$ of the edges touch at least one red vertex. 
Define $p(G,r)$ as the probability that a graph $G$ is $r$-good. Obviously $p(G,r)$ is decreasing with $r$.

**What is the largest $r$ such that $p(G,r)>1/2$ for all finite graphs $G$?**

There is an upper bound of $2/3$ (as noted by Kevin P. Costello) and a lower bound of $1/2$.

- For the upper bound, let $G$ be the clique with $3$ vertices. It has eight different colorings: one is 0-good, three are 2/3-good and four are 1-good. Therefore, $p(G,2/3)= 7/8$, but for every $r>2/3$, $p(G,r)\leq 1/2$.
- For the lower bound, consider an arbitrary graph $G$. For every coloring of $G$, either it or its opposite colorng is $1/2$-good; therefore $p(G,1/2)\geq 1/2$. To prove that $p(G,1/2)>1/2$, it is sufficient to prove the existence of a coloring that both it and its opposite are $1/2$-good. To construct such a coloring, assign a unique number to each vertex of $G$, and assign to each edge $(u,v)$ the number $(u+v)/2$. Let $D$ be the median of all edges' numbers. Color all vertices smaller than $D$ red and all other vertices blue. Both this coloring and its opposite are $1/2$-good. Hence $p(G,1/2)>1/2$.

Intuitively, the 3-clique seems to be the worst case, since when there are many vertices, the expected number of good edges is $3/4$. So my conjecture is that the real value is 2/3. In other words:

**Conjecture.** For every finite graph $G$, $p(G,2/3)>1/2$.

Is this true? Alternatively, can you prove tighter bounds?

Comment: For $K_3$ we have $p(r) = 1/2$ for any $r>2/3$.  It wouldn't surprise me if the lower bound approached $3/4$ as the size of the graph tended to infinity.  With very high probability, a random coloring will have about half the edges connecting red and blue (since different edges being bicolored are pairwise independent).  Half the time you have as many red-red edges than blue-blue edges.  Unfortunately, this only gets you $1/2-\epsilon$ probability, instead of greater than $1/2$.

Comment: Interesting. So the gap is now [1/2,2/3], and if it ineed increases with the graph size then the real answer should be 2/3. But I do not understand the statement on bicolored edges: if in K3 two edges are bicolored then the third edge cannot be bicolored?!

Comment: This is as the number of edges goes to infinity.  In a graph with $m$ vertices, the expected number of bicolored edges is $m/2$, and the variance is $m/4$, so there's concentration by Chebyshev's inequality if nothing else.

Comment: Szemerédi regularity lemma guaranties that the conjecture holds for graphs with sufficiently many vertices. It remains to verify "only" finitely many graphs. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

For $r > 1/2$, consider the [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) $K_{1,n}$ for large $n$.  Half of the time, the central vertex will be red, and the graph will certainly be $r$-good.  The other half of the time, the central vertex will be blue, and the graph will be $r$-good only if a fraction $r$ of the other vertices are red.  The probability of this event approaches $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  So the probability of a large star graph being $r$-good (for $r > 1/2$) is only slightly greater than $1/2$.

You have defined $p(r)$ to be the smallest probability that a graph is $r$-good.  In this case, there may not be a smallest probability; the probabilities approach a limit of $1/2$ (unless of course there is some other graph I have not considered which has a smaller probability of being $r$-good).  So, if it is fair to alter the statement of the question to define $p(r)$ as the infimum of all such probabilities, then $p(r) \leq 1/2$ for all $r > 1/2$.

Comment: Indeed, there might be no "smallest probability", but still, for every finite graph the probability is larger than $1/2$. I edited the question to better clarify the intention.